# Issue after submitting my app to TestFlight

Tags: bundle, dylib

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "AppName". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

**Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.**

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

Answer (score 2):

For me the following worked:

1. i updated cocoapods [if You have troubles doing so this link may help](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692)
2. deleted MyProjectTests (that i wasn't using)
3. deleted my `Pods/` folder and `Podfile.lock`
4. made `pod install`
5. rebooted my mac

and the problem is gone

Comment: What version of cocoa pods was this?

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen the problem after install the app in a real device, but crashed (in the simulator works). My app missing a library installed with Cocoapods.